# How are $R$-linear maps a $k$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $R=M_n(D)$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra (k a field) where $D$ is a skew field. It is well known that there is a unique simple left $R$-module $V$. I then know that

$$D \cong \operatorname{End}_R(V)$$

My book then claims that $D$ is a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra. In what way is this defined?

I guess, somehow we have to put a $k$-algebra structure on $\operatorname{End}_R(V)$.

How is this done?

Comment: Do you know the ring-structure of the "endomorphism ring"? Can you think of a reasonable ring map $k\to\mathrm{End}_R(V)$? Or a reasonable ring map $R\to \mathrm{End}_R(V)$?

Comment: $r \mapsto (x \mapsto rx)$ would be a map $R \to \operatorname{End}_R(V)$. I can see that there is an action of $k$ on the endomorphism ring if $V$ is somehow a $k$-module, but I want the end result to be finite dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The core queston

You already have that $M_n(D)$ is a finite dimensional $k$ algebra, and it contains an isomorphic copy of $D$, namely the constant diagonal matrices.

As a subalgebra of a finite dimensional $k$ algebra, $D$ must have finite $k$ dimension as well.

### The question you were pursuing

In this case, it is customary to write $V$ as an $R,D$ bimodule like this: $_RV_D$, and remember that the elements of $R$ are $D$ right $D$-linear and the elements of $End_R(V)$ are left $R$ linear.

The natural action, then, for an $f\in End_R(V)$ and $\lambda \in k$ is $(\lambda\cdot f)(x)=f(x\lambda)$.

For if $r$ is any element of $R$, $(\lambda\cdot f)(rx)=f(rx\lambda)=rf(x\lambda)=r[(\lambda\cdot f)(x)]$, so $\lambda\cdot f$ is indeed left $R$ linear, showing (the hard part) that the subalgebra is closed under this scalar action.

Comment: So easy I'm embarassed. Thanks.